# Convert htaccess to lighttpd

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I've my testing environment as Apache and I've a .htaccess file with some simple rewrite URL rules, and to push this to live, our live server uses lighttpd and we want to convert the rules to be written for lighttpd.

The requirements is for some URL like:
`http://www2.mydomain.com/content/myfile.docs?param1=val1&param2=val2`
I want this to be mapped/rewritten as:
`http://www2.mydomain.com/content/index.php?file_name=myfile.docs&param1=val1&param2=val2`

Note: The domain name is dynamic, so I want this to work for different domain names [like `www2.mydomain.com`, `cdn.domainname.com` etc...]

Note: My htaccess rewrite rules are:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?vanity_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've checked several topics [like this one http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/5465], but couldn't get it working,
I made sure the rewrite module is enabled on my server, and here is the "lighttpd" file content I used:

```
server.error-handler-404 = "/index.php" 

url.rewrite-once = (
"^(.*)\~s(\?,*)$" => "/index.php?file_name=$1"
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You need to demonstrate at least a little effort to solve this yourself, including what you've coded so far, working or not. If you post your progress and why it isn't working we can help. But posting your requirements and just expecting it to get written for you isn't how things work here.

Comment: Sorry If I did not mention the effort I did trying to get this resolved, I did not know it is important.
I've modified the problem description, I hope this can help.
Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Your regex is a mess, like, the `\~s`, what is that supposed to match? Have you ever used anything like [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)? You need to match everything before the file name: `(.*)`, then, the filename, being anything but a question mark `/([^?]*)`, finally, the query string: `?(.*)`. Then turn it into `$1/index.php?file_name=$2&$3` But if there isn't a query string at all that won't work right either.